# Google BigQuery aggregate OHLC data over time window

Tags: google-bigquery, time-series, finance

There is time series trading transactions history stored with google's BigQuery.

```
# Transaction history scheme

exchange_id INTEGER REQUIRED  
from_id INTEGER REQUIRED    
to_id   INTEGER REQUIRED    
price   FLOAT   REQUIRED    
size    FLOAT   REQUIRED    
ts  TIMESTAMP   REQUIRED    
is_sell BOOLEAN NULLABLE    
_PARTITIONTIME  TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE
```

**exchange_id** - platform where transation occured
**from_id** - base symbol
**to_id**   - quote symbol
**price**   - trade price
**size**    - trade quantity

I need to aggregate [OHLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-high-low-close_chart) data over 30 seconds time interval grouped by
 `exchange_id, from_id, to_id`. How can I do this in the BigQuery?

```
# Required OHLC aggregated data scheme

ts  TIMESTAMP   REQUIRED 
exchange_id INTEGER REQUIRED  
from_id INTEGER REQUIRED    
to_id   INTEGER REQUIRED    
open   FLOAT   REQUIRED    
high   FLOAT   REQUIRED    
low   FLOAT   REQUIRED    
close   FLOAT   REQUIRED    
volume    FLOAT   REQUIRED 
_PARTITIONTIME  TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE
```

**open** - first price in interval
**high** - highest price..
**low** - lowest price..
**close** - last price..
**volume** - SUM of all trade size's in current interval

---

Most promising ideas were:

```
SELECT 
    TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(
      UNIX_SECONDS(ts) -
      60 * 1000000
    ) AS time,
    exchange_id,
    from_id,
    to_id,
    MIN(price) as low,
    MAX(price) as high,
    SUM(size) as volume
FROM 
    `table`
GROUP BY
  time, exchange_id, from_id, to_id
ORDER BY
  time
```

And this one:

```
SELECT 
  exchange_id,from_id,to_id,
  MAX(price) OVER (PARTITION BY exchange_id,from_id,to_id ORDER BY ts RANGE BETWEEN 60 * 1000000 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as high,
  MIN(price) OVER (PARTITION BY exchange_id,from_id,to_id ORDER BY ts RANGE BETWEEN 60 * 1000000 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as low,
  SUM(size) OVER (PARTITION BY exchange_id,from_id,to_id ORDER BY ts RANGE BETWEEN 60 * 1000000 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as volume,
FROM   [table];


# returns:
1   1   4445    3808    9.0E-8  9.0E-8  300000.0     
2   1   4445    3808    9.0E-8  9.0E-8  300000.0     
3   1   4445    3808    9.0E-8  9.0E-8  300000.0     
...
14  1   4445    3808    9.0E-8  9.0E-8  865939.3721800799    
15  1   4445    3808    9.0E-8  9.0E-8  865939.3721800799    
16  1   4445    3808    9.0E-8  9.0E-8  865939.3721800799
```

But nothing of this works. It seems that I missing something important about sliding window in BigQuery.

Comment: and what you tried so far? :) otherwise you might meant to use https://www.mturk.com or similar sites

Comment: thank you for updating! from glance  - second one looks promising. are you getting some error here? and - what is the datatype of ts?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I will never ask a question before spending few hours solving it, but now I'm really stuck... This question seems to be common and I think it won't be redundant on SO.

Comment: ts  TIMESTAMP   REQUIRED

Comment: sure, no problem. good/normal question here. please clarify  - are you getting any error for second query

Comment: No, there is no error.. just a lot of similar rows (added to question). And I have no idea how to group them by time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardsql
SELECT 
  exchange_id, 
  from_id, 
  to_id,
  TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(DIV(UNIX_SECONDS(ts), 30) * 30) time,
  ARRAY_AGG(price ORDER BY ts LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] open,
  MAX(price) high,
  MIN(price) low,
  ARRAY_AGG(price ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] close,
  SUM(size) volume
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable`
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Have found an elegant way to make aggregation over predefined `date_parts` ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#datetime_trunc)). It's very helpful when you need to aggregate over Mondays or Months.

**DATETIME_TRUNC** support next parameters:

```
MICROSECOND
MILLISECOND
SECOND
MINUTE
HOUR
DAY
WEEK
WEEK(<WEEKDAY>)
MONTH
QUARTER
YEAR
```

You can aggregate use it like this:

```
#standardsql

SELECT 
  TIMESTAMP(DATETIME_TRUNC(DATETIME(timestamp), DAY)) as timestamp,
  ARRAY_AGG(open ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] open,
  MAX(high) high,
  MIN(low) low,
  ARRAY_AGG(close ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] close,
  SUM(volume) volume
FROM `hcmc-project.test_bitfinex.BTC_USD__1h`
GROUP BY timestamp
ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```